# How to minimize temperature increase caused by compression of a cryogenic liquid in a multistage high pressure turbopump?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, aerospace-engineering, rocketry

The cryogenic fuel I'm using is methane at 100 K and 300,000 Pa.

Based on my calculations, after compression, the pressure is 55 MPa and using the ideal gas equation the temperature is approx. 800 K.

I need to keep the methane at a temperature of 300 K - 600 K preferably as close to 300 K as possible.

I am after any designs or solutions to keep the temperature low, like regenerative cooling, or is that just ridiculous?

The application is for a rocket, temperatures in the vicinity will be high.

Comment: If the methane is at 100K (if by k you actually mean Kelvin) then it is a liquid... so why use the ideal gas equations?

Comment: got mixed up I'm going to go and recalculate and then edit the question my apologize about that

Comment: Plus 1 for a good attitude ...